# How to collect and gather words from multiple lines in a input text (PDB file) using Python?

Tags: python

I am coding a Python script that collect words in a text file (PDB file), later gathering them in phrases. However, as I am just a beginner in programming, I'm having huge difficulties in doing it. I know how to do it just one line per time. I wish you guys could give me some help. Please.

The text has informations about **sites** of a protein. Each site has **four dedicated lines** of information, as you can see below:

```
REMARK 800  
REMARK 800 SITE_IDENTIFIER: CC1                                                 
REMARK 800 EVIDENCE_CODE: SOFTWARE                                              
REMARK 800 SITE_DESCRIPTION: BINDING SITE FOR RESIDUE EDO A 326                 
REMARK 800                                                                      
REMARK 800 SITE_IDENTIFIER: DF8                                                 
REMARK 800 EVIDENCE_CODE: AUTHOR                                             
REMARK 800 SITE_DESCRIPTION: BINDING SITE FOR RESIDUE HEM T 238
REMARK 800                                                                      
REMARK 800 SITE_IDENTIFIER: FC7                                                 
REMARK 800 EVIDENCE_CODE: SOFTWARE                                              
REMARK 800 SITE_DESCRIPTION: BINDING SITE FOR RESIDUE NAG D 1001 

#and so on ...
```

An extended exemple is seen in the following link (search for "REMARK 800"):
http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/3HDL.pdb

As observed,

- The **1st** line has nothing. *(It just separates one information from the next)*
- the **2nd** has the **SITE_IDENTIFIER**. *(e.g. CC1)*
- the **3rd**, the **EVIDENCE_CODE**. *(e.g. SOFTWARE)*
- the **4th**, some **RESIDUE** informations. *(e.g. EDO A 326)*

This pattern is seen in a great part of the text.

What I want to do is to gather some words from three of the four consecutive dedicated lines, in such way that they are put together in one phrase. The necessary informations are the **SITE_IDENTIFIER**, the **EVIDENCE_CODE**, and **3 words** from **SITE_DESCRIPTION**. Thus, concerning the text excerpt above, the resulting phrases would be something like this:

```
CC1 SOFTWARE EDO A 326
DF8 AUTHOR HEM T 238
FC7 SOFTWARE NAG D 1001

#and so on...
```

Is it possible to do? If so, can you guys imagine how can I do this?

I tried doing it this way, but I feel like it is not going to work at all:

```
name_file = "3HDL.pdb"

pdb_file = open(name_file,"r")

for line in pdb_file:
    list = line.split()

    list_2=[]
    for j in range(0, 15):
        list_2.append("")

    if (list[0] == "REMARK" and list[1] == "800"):
        j=0
        while not j == len(list):
            list_2[j] = list[j]
            j+=1

        n=1
        if(list_2[0] == "REMARK" and list_2[1] == "800" and list_2[2] == "SITE_IDENTIFIER:"):
            n+=1
            print("Site", str(n) + ":", list_2[3])
            print("ok" + "\n")
```

As you can see, I am really a beginner.

Sorry about any grammar problems and thank you very much.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: Before we start downvoting your question. Please show us that you have demonstrated some ability to problem solve this yourself.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, it's my first time here.

Comment: For sure, James. I'll put here what i've done until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
import re

f = open("3HDL.pdb", "r")

for line in f:
  m = re.search(r"REMARK 800 SITE_IDENTIFIER: (.+)", line)
  if m:
    site_id = m.group(1).strip()
  else:
    m = re.search(r"REMARK 800 EVIDENCE_CODE: (.+)", line)
    if m:
      evidence_code = m.group(1).strip()
    else:
      m = re.search(r"REMARK 800 SITE_DESCRIPTION: (.+)", line)
      if m:
        site_descrip = m.group(1).strip()
        print site_id, evidence_code, site_descrip

f.close()
```

Or, if you want to avoid using the regex module:

```
f = open("3HDL.pdb", "r")

for line in f:
  if line.startswith("REMARK 800"):
    if line.startswith("SITE_IDENTIFIER:", 11):
      site_id = line[28:].rstrip()
    elif line.startswith("EVIDENCE_CODE:", 11):
      evidence_code = line[26:].rstrip()
    elif line.startswith("SITE_DESCRIPTION:", 11):
      site_descrip = line[29:].rstrip()
      print site_id, evidence_code, site_descrip

f.close()
```

Comment: Good use of RegEx. Elegant solution.

Comment: Just for fun: OneLiner to dazzle your friend, extended from above answer: `print '\n'.join(' '.join(i) for i in re.findall("REMARK 800 SITE_IDENTIFIER: (\w+)\s+REMARK 800 EVIDENCE_CODE: (\w+)\s+REMARK 800 SITE_DESCRIPTION: BINDING SITE FOR RESIDUE (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)", f.read()))`

Comment: Hardcoded string position is a very ugly position, ooga. Why not do a `split` and get negative index. :| Anyhow, I think the RegEx solution is the most elegant.

Comment: @NhatNgo I agree. :-)

Comment: Thank you ooga and @Nhat Ngo for the support! It is exactly what I wanted. The first option, as Nhat said seems to be very pratical indeed. However, as I started learning Python a month ago, it is easier to me to understand the second option, although it is not really elegant. But later I will search for some informations about Regular Expressions. Do you guys recommend me any source of information for it? Once more, thank you very much!

Comment: @daniel_trinunes This book on WikiBook: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions
and this chapter in NTLK by Steven Bird: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html are good start.

Answer (score -1):

Here we assume the content wanted are the last word of line 2,3 and the last 3 words of line 4.

```
name_file = "3HDL.pdb"
pdb_file = open(name_file,"r")
output = []
for linenum, line in enumerate(pdb_file):
    if linenum % 4 ==0:
        continue
    elif linenum % 4 == 1:
        output.append(line.split()[-1])
    elif linenum % 4 == 2:
        output.append(line.split()[-1])
    elif linenum % 4 == 3:
        output.extend(line.split()[-3:])
for i in range(len(output)/6):
    print ' '.join(output[i:i+6])
```

Comment: Look at attached file structure, this won't work as there are other tags in the file.

Comment: As I checked, the REMARK 800 section has the exact structure.

Comment: The `re` solution is better in general cases but a overkill here.

Comment: Look at the attached file <http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/3HDL.pdb>. Your solution does not handle other tag declaration. Hence calling `pdb_file = open(name_file,"r")` is wrong.

Comment: `re` solution is also more readable. I would not call it overkill.